# Ajax prevent form action and post form data

Tags: php, ajax, forms, jquery, post

I have been searching through examples for days trying to troubleshoot my simple email signup form. I am trying to just submit an email to a database without leaving or reloading the current page. I am able to insert new data to my database, **but not through my Ajax function**. I am starting to think that my Ajax function is not being called, because even with the `event.preventDefault();` function, my page is redirected to the .php file. I have listed my script below which currently resides in the `<head></head>` section of my HTML.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(Function() {
    $("#submitbtn").click(function(event) {

            event.preventDefault();

        var form = $(this),  
            emailcode = form.serialize(),
            formUrl = form.attr('action'),
            formMethod = form.attr('method');
            /* responseMsg = $('#signup-response') */

            if ( formData.length===0 ) {

            function(msg){
            alert('Invalid Email');
            }
            return false;
            } else {

            //send data to server  
            $.ajax({  
                url: formUrl,
                type: formMethod,
                data: emailcode,
                success:function(data){
                alert('Email Saved');
        } 

        return false;
          });
      };
   });
});
```

HTML

```
<form class="col-lg-5 form-group pull-right well" id="emailform" action="collector.php" method="POST" style="padding-top:6px;">
      <label for="email-input">Sign up to receive updates</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailcode" placeholder="Email" name="emaildata" autofocus></input>
      <button type="submit" id="submitbtn" class="btn btn-success" style="width:60%">Sign Up</button>
      </form>
```

PHP

```
    $emailcode = $_POST['emailcode'];

            //Fetching from your database table.
            $query = "INSERT INTO EmailCollector (EmailID, EmailCode, Active)
            VALUES (NULL,'$emailcode', 0)";
            $result = mysql_query($query);

    mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: Try changing " var form = $(this) " in to var form = $('#emailform')" . And what is 'formData' ?

Comment: 'formData' is now 'emailcode'. Your suggestion did not change any output, but thanks for catching my stupid variable error.

Answer (score 1):

A quick thing i noticed.

```
form = $(this)  //it is holding submit button, not the form
emailcode = form.serialize(),
formUrl = form.attr('action'), //there is no attribute `action` to select because form is holding submit button
formMethod = form.attr('method'); //similarly, there is no attribute method
```

change your form selector to:

```
form = $('#emailForm')
```

Comment: I changed to `form = $('#emailForm')`. I also changed `form.attr('action')` and `form.attr('method')` to `"collector.php"` and `"post"` respectively. Results have not changed, still being directed to .php page and not passing any data to the .php file.